# Waking from sleep causes instant shutoff

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, power-supply, sleep

I am going to be very detailed as this seems extremely confusing to me ...

I just completed upgrading a few components in one of my builds (list of components at end of thread). Everything works perfectly until I wake my computer from sleep (I put my PC to sleep very often when I am away). I put it to sleep perfectly fine, I even left it on sleep for 9 hours yesterday, no problems. As soon as I woke it up, it turned on for 1 sec, and quickly shut off. Then, around 2 seconds later, with no intervention, it turned on and shut off very quickly; this time with the PSU's OC/OV protection click being heard. As I am wondering what is happening, it automatically boots up the 3rd time and hangs with no post except a steady red LED under the GPU. Since nothing was happening, I hit the reset button on the computer, and it started to boot again. Passed post, booted into windows, no errors. Now when I put it to sleep again, the same thing happens upon wake up. I began changing everything: power settings (PCI link power settings, Hybrid sleep OFF, Turn off HDDs OFF), MSI AfterBurner voltage settings, raising the PSU's OverCurrent protection threshold (from 30 amps to 35 amps; per rail), but to no avail.

*RUNNING WINDOWS 8.1 w/ LATEST UPDATES*

Previous System Specs (no problem):

-Asus Sabertooth P67 (Rev 3)
-Intel Core i7 2700K @ 4.4 GHz
-G.Skill 2x4GB @ 1600 OCed @ 1866
-G.Skill 2x4GB @ 1866 stock
-Gigabyte GTX 970 G1 4GB
-Samsung 840 Evo 120 GB
-Samsung 840 Evo 240 GB
-WD BLUE 500 GB 7200 RPM
-WD BLACK 320 GB 7200 RPM
-Toshiba 1TB 5400 RPM
-Antec EarthWatts 750 watts

NEW System Specs (wake-up hang):

-Asus Sabertooth P67 (Rev 3)
-Intel Core i7 2700K @ 4.4 GHz
-**Removed**
-G.Skill 2x4GB @ 1866 stock
-Gigabyte GTX 970 G1 4GB
-** Samsung 850 Pro 128 GB **
-Samsung 840 Evo 240 GB
-WD BLUE 500 GB 7200 RPM
-**Removed**
-Toshiba 1TB 5400 RPM
-** Corsair AX 860i PSU **

I am assuming that it is my PSU shutting off in order to protect components from OverCurrent. I assume that during wakeup, the GTX 970 pulls more than 35 amps of current through one of the external PCI ports. I can manually adjust the OC protection threshold or even disable it completely but I am afraid of doing that until I get some confirmations.

Comment: Rails, you mention them, what is the layout of the 12V rails on the PSU and how are they utalised?  When shifting stuff around, did you possibly rearrange how the rails (seperate curcuits with power protection) were powering various hardwares?  It is not clear what you mean in the last paragraph when you say "external PCI ports" or I did not read it well enough?  Did you mean the 8or6pin extra power wires going to the GTX 970?  What is the voltage your applying to the GPU processor and ram?  I think often people underestimate the increase in current from minor voltage increases.

Comment: The layout of the 12V rails are "virtual" meaning its PHYSICALLY a single rail design, but through its software, it is set to run in "multi-rail mode" as an added safety feature. I can go into details on how that works, but I will not in this comment.

Yes, by external PCI cables, I mean the 8 and 6 pin external connectors that hook up to the GTX 970.

ALL voltages are stock, on the CPU, GPU, and RAM.

Comment: Ugg, software playing with the PSU , could they find anything else to mess up :-) Looking at the list of what has changed, and what problem you have , it (as you well know) points to an issue with the PSU or how it is set-up, like it cant be those other things, unless you left a screw sticking out (a standoff missing, or something odd).  If it was any of the over-wattage or over current settings via the uefi/bios it should drop out hard when working the CPU hard like using prime. For the GPU you could test FURmark. could be software still i suppose, many systems do not standby well?

Comment: I am currently taking the Software approach, uninstall programs and restarting 1 by 1. Are there any Hardware things I can attempt?

I will run CPU and GPU burners and see if it crashes.